# The best way to store user info along with credentials in Swift

Tags: swift, mobile

What is the best practice to store user info in Swift app?

I user third-party service (firebase) to manage authentications and I wonder where to store credentials returned along with email or other user data (e.g. name, surname...).

According to available options I see that delegation to different services (Keychain + Core data) is the best solution here but is it worth it?

Comment: The most secure option would be to store the credentials in the Keychain. Not much hassle to access it. Just use some library.